# How do I delete Zelle graphics text from the screen in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, zelle-graphics

I would like to delete text that I have graphically displayed so I can write new text without overlap.  I  have included my code below.  Thank you again for your time.

```
from graphics import*
import random

# Function for winning
def youwin():
    txt = Text(Point(250,100), "You are a Winner!")
    txt.setTextColor(color_rgb(0,255,200))
    txt.setSize(30)
    txt.setFace('courier')
    txt.draw(win)

# Function for losing    
def youlose():

txt= Text(Point(250,100), "You are a Loser!")
txt.setTextColor(color_rgb(0,255,0))
txt.setSize(30)
txt.setFace('courier')
txt.draw(win)


# Sets a Window
win = GraphWin("My Window", 800, 600)
win.setBackground('White')

# loops 10 Times and picks out 3 random gif's.
# Then displays each image on the screen in a row.

for x in range(10):

cards = ["1.png","2.png","3.png"]
rand_card1 = random.choice(cards)      
img1 = Image(Point(100, 250), rand_card1)
rand_card2 = random.choice(cards)
img2 = Image(Point(300, 250), rand_card2)
rand_card3 = random.choice(cards)
img3 = Image(Point(500, 250), rand_card3)


img1.draw(win) 
img2.draw(win)
img3.draw(win)

# checks to see if you are a winner

if rand_card1 == rand_card2 and rand_card2 == rand_card3:
    youwin()
else:
    youlose()


# waits for a mouse click.  In the future this will be a button.    
win.getMouse()    
img1.undraw()
img2.undraw()
img3.undraw()



#win.close()#
```

This is the output I currently get:

[image: Double text outputted to screen]

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with what you're using, but I'm imagining you might want to somehow clear your drawing area *before* you draw new text there. I would look for either a screen-clearing function or draw a rectangle over the old text that's the same color as the background. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me will get what I'm saying and post the exact code needed below... But this is what my general approach would be.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, the rectangle worked!!!    I am sure I am not coding efficiently but as a newbie, I'll take what I can get :)  Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: [Done.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479477/3775798)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to somehow clear your drawing area before you draw new text there. One approach to this would be to draw a rectangle over your old text which is the same color as the background.

Comment: @Jason,  this is not a good solution for Zelle graphics.  Consider text that is counting down.  Each time you change the number, you'd be associating two more graphic objects with the window, the blanking rectangle and the new text.  Instead, you simply can tell the old text object to `undraw()` itself before creating a new one, or, better yet, tell that same text object to `setText("new text")` to display the new text and not delete, nor create, anything additional.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to delete text that I have graphically displayed so I can
>   write new text

Don't.  You can reuse the text object via `setText()`.  A simple example:

```
import time  # just for demonstration
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("My Window", 800, 600)

txt = Text(Point(250,100), "You are a Loser!")
txt.setSize(30)
txt.draw(win)

time.sleep(3)

txt.setText("You are a Winner!")

time.sleep(3)
```

If you want the text to disappear for a time, just `txt.setText('')` until you need it again.

Comment: I don't think the above code works :(  I am not sure what a "Zelle" graphic is.  I am using graphics.py.  Thank you for answering though :)

Comment: I see now "Zelle" is the creator of graphics.py.  Ok its back to youtube for more introductory videos :)

Comment: @Jason, I just copied the above code, pasted into a file and ran it.  It runs fine for me, what doesn't work?  Please provide the error messages.